# Changing content of slider with ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-slider

I have to do the following thing: I have a content-slider beneath a image-slider. Everytime the person switches between the categories of the content-slider, the image-slider should show another set of pictures (I work with wordpress, so it's another loop of category) but without reloading the whole site.

Do you know any good resource for that?

Answer (score 0):

Something like -

In you php that will serve up the images -

```
if($_GET['ajax'] == 1) {
  //echo relevant images;
}
```

and the jQuery code would be

```
function sliderMove() {
  //may also need to pass slider id in here so you know what images to get
  $("#picturediv").load("./test.php?ajax=1");
  //OR
  //to customize your call more, you could do
  $.ajax({
   method: "GET",
   url: "./test.php?ajax=1",
   success: function(data) { $("#picturediv").html(data); },
   error: function(err){ Some_Error_Div.innerHTML = err; }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well I would suggest something diffrent from the above solution.. Extend the jquery library so that you can initilize it with a bunch of classes that you need to hide/display depending on the slider level.

The extension will accept an array of different classes that are given to your various divs
say

var  level=   ['.div1','.div2','.div3']

now based on where the slider is you will hide/show that div.

thus if the slider is at 2 then you do something like `$(level[2]).show()` and `$(level[1]).hide() and $(level[3]).hide()`

or you can use a library like: http://nivo.dev7studios.com/#usage

here are some more: http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/